# How to add Fee to Selected Payment Methods in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I have multiple payment methods in Magento 1.7.0.2

For some I would like to add an extra Fee for some of them.

How can I do that?

Ps: if there is a community based extension which may be extended or may even suffice would also be great, actually that would be life saver as of now.

Comment: http://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-surcharge.html

Comment: I was looking to extend a community based edition.

Comment: Maybe this can be extended.. but I really don't know how?

Comment: The extension docs say it will run on Magento Community (including 1.7.0.2), and I think it does what you want right out of the box.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can extend Shopping Cart Price Rules functionality by [editing core files](http://php.quicoto.com/extra-fee-shopping-cart-price-rules-magento/) or writing extension with this idea (allow negative discounts for Shopping Cart rules).
There is a [paid extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16306/) for it where some problems are solved that are not considered in article above.

You can also write extension that uses different idea - add your own total. But this is more complex.

Comment: Editing Core Files is a bad idea and not a way of good Magento development.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a similar soution. I've just installed this extension to extend the shopping cart rules with fees. This should work. http://shop.etwebsolutions.com/eng/et-extrachargeforcartrules.html

Answer (score 0):

Got here from Google and got the idea there were only paid solutions. If someone is still looking for this, this module is currently free and delivers:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/payment-method-charge.html